# Using stdin with a daemon process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script that needs to be running 24/7, so I have been running it using pm2. However, I also would like to be able to occasionally check on the script. Before running it as a daemon I set it to read the stdin, but for daemons this does not work. Is there a simple way to do this and run a daemon process?

I understand that this is pretty contradictory to the nature of daemons, but I need the script to run continuously and have limited user input.

Comment: Maybe use a "named pipe" or put some socket code into your daemon.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using [`process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), the following example is taken from the book: [Professional Node.js](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/professional-nodejs-pedro-teixeira/1111115797/2678514135402?st=PLA&sid=BNB_DRS_New%20Marketplace%20Shopping%20Books_00000000&2sid=Google_&sourceId=PLGoP164949&gclid=CjwKCAiAu4nRBRBKEiwANms5Wz7SCgkVVuHDdoapioNYOLLwEedC5b4ElfRQ_MUnzeJQL2xnGtAZtBoCPxcQAvD_BwE)

Create a file named plus_one.js:

```
// unpause the stdin stream 
process.stdin.resume(); 
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
var number; 
try {
  // parse the input data into a number 
  number = parseInt(data.toString(), 10);

  // increment by one 
  number += 1;
  // output the number
  process.stdout.write(number + "\n"); 
 } catch(err) {
    process.stderr.write(err.message + "\n"); 
 }
});
```

You can run this simple program by calling:

```
$ node plus_one.js
```

create a file named plus_one_test.js:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
// Spawn the child with a node process executing the plus_one app var 
child = spawn('node', ['plus_one.js']);
// Call this function every 1 second (1000 milliseconds): 
setInterval(function() {
// Create a random number smaller than 10.000 
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
// Send that number to the child process: 
  child.stdin.write(number + "\n");
// Get the response from the child process and print it: 
  child.stdout.once('data', function(data) {
    console.log('child replied to ' + number + ' with: ' + data); 
  });
}, 1000);
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) { 
  process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

Here you launch the +1 app as a child process on lines 1 to 4.
Then you use the setInterval function to do the following every second:
Create a random natural number smaller than 10,000. Send that number as a string to the child process. Wait for the child process to reply with a string.